# using OOP on .click function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a webpage that has a baseball strikezone with 25 buttons that will be clickable in 25 locations.  I need to know if there is a easier way to do this then what I am doing. Maybe something that will take up far less lines. The button is clicked and then the counter is added by one to another table.

```
$('#one').click(function(){
    counter++;
        $('#ones').text(counter);

     });
     var countertwo = 0;
     $('#two').click(function(){
     countertwo ++;
     $('#twos').text(countertwo);
     });
```

Comment: We need a lot more detail about the problem in order to usefully help. Showing the HTML would help, for instance, along with a clearer explanation of what `#one` and `#ones` and such are.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a guess here, but:

- You can store the counter on the button itself.
- If you do, and you give the buttons a common class (or some other way to group them), you can have one click handler handle all of them.
- You can probably find the other element that you're updating using a structural CSS query rather than `id` values.

But relying on those ID values:

```
$(".the-common-class").click(function() {
    // Get a jQuery wrapper for this element.
    var $this = $(this);

    // Get its counter, if it has one, or 0 if it doesn't, and add one to it
    var counter = ($this.data("counter") || 0) + 1;

    // Store the result
    $this.data("counter", counter);

    // Show that in the other element, basing the ID of what we look for
    // on this element's ID plus "s"
    $("#" + this.id + "s").text(counter);
});
```

That last bit, relating the elements by ID naming convention, is the weakest bit and could almost certainly be made much better with more information about your structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
<button class="button" data-location="ones">One</button>
...
<button class="button" data-location="twenties">Twenty</button>

<div id="ones" class="location">0</div>
...
<div id="twenties" class="location">0</div>

$('.button').on('click', function() {
  var locationId = $(this).data('location')
    , $location = $('#' + locationId);

  $location.text(parseInt($location.text()) + 1);
});
```

Also see this code on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mlipilin/yxLj8kpf/)

Comment: this is literally exactly what I was looking for thanks you very much

Comment: FWIW, `data` is not an accessor function for `data-*` attributes, it does both more and less than that. Unless you need the `data` features, use `.attr("data-location")` instead. (Also not a fan of storing data in the UI rather than just having the UI *reflect* the data, but that's a design call and people go both ways.)

Comment: You can use either `.attr('data-location')` or `.data('location')`, they are both working. But I agree with you, `.attr` is more preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

More clean solution with automatic counter

```js
/* JS */

$(function() {
  var $buttons = $('.withCounter'),
      counters = [];
  
  function increaseCounter() {
    var whichCounter = $buttons.index(this)+1;
    counters[whichCounter] = counters[whichCounter] ? counters[whichCounter] += 1 : 1;
    $("#counter"+whichCounter).text(counters[whichCounter]);
  }
  
  $buttons.click(increaseCounter);
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<button class="withCounter">One</button>
<button class="withCounter">Two</button>
<button class="withCounter">Three</button>
<button class="withCounter">Four</button>

<p id="counter1">0</p>
<p id="counter2">0</p>
<p id="counter3">0</p>
<p id="counter4">0</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```